# Redirecting stdout to remote terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdout

Let me start off by saying that I am in no way at all very skilled in this, 
so apologies if this has been asked/answered before.
Basically I've installed Ubuntu on my moms laptop and I'm looking for a way 
to be able to redirect stdout from her computer directly to my own terminal.

What I have is pretty basic but,
on my machine (A) I open a listening port with

```
nc -l -v -p (1111)
```

on my moms machine (B)

```
nc -nv x.x.x.x(my IP) 1111 -e /bin/bash
```

So far so good.
I can do a `cd /var/log` and `ls` and see the contents,
but when I try to either `more` or `cat` a file, the screen remains blank.

If I do a `cat messages > /dev/tty 2>&1`, she tells me that she sees whatever I type on her own terminal,
but I don't get to see the contents at all, just the command itself.

I've also tried, opening a listening port on my end and on her machine,

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/x.x.x.x/1111 0>&1.
```

Now with this, I can see that my machine (A) 'becomes' her machine (B) shell, but again,
when doing cat or less or whatnot, the screen remains blank.

I'm using Debian on my end, and from what I've read and from checking /dev, there is no tcp descriptor.
If I try per example, `

```
cat messages &> /dev/stdout/x.x.x.x(my IP)/1111
```

I get `/dev/stdout/x.x.x.x/22: Not a directory`

How can I redirect the output directly to terminal and not to a txt file?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Why aren't you using `ssh` to connect to remote machines?

Comment: I think you meant `/dev/tcp/x.x.x.x/1111` in the last case.

Comment: I'm actually using VNC to connect. But I'm quite sure there must be a way to do it with nc/shell. Tx for the comment. ☺

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with buffering in `nc`.

Comment: You really should use `ssh`; it is designed for such cases, and it is very common and easy to use (and supported by many other utilities, e.g. [git](http://git-scm.com/)....); I see no reason to avoid using `ssh` ; besides, your approach might have big security holes....

Comment: Check the man pages of the `talk` command. What exactly are you _trying to accomplish_, and not what _you're trying to do_? Two different things. Why do you need to see what's on her terminal? Do you need to see her error messages or do you want to be able to log into that computer? We could recommend other utilities that can accomplish exactly what you wan to do.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the input. I have VNC running on her computer so on that end I'm OK. But I really don' t like not knowing why something isn't working. I want to read messages for example. I know I can redirect stdout to a txt file and then pass it on (or I can simply VNC and run it locally on her terminal) but, I simply want to understand why I can ls but not cat. Tx again

Answer (score 0):

You can connect via several means at the same time. That means you can use VNC to see what she is doing on the desktop. If you need to check something, you can connect via SSH *in addition* to the current VNC session. That way, you can run all kinds of commands in the background (for example to install updates) without bothering your mom.

Since the built-in security of VNC isn't that great, you can combine the two. Many VNS clients have options to enable SSH. If that doesn't help, you can start SSH and add port forwarding of the remote VNC port (which only needs to be available for `localhost`, not for the whole Internet) to your computer. You can then run your local VNC client against the local port and SSH will make sure that this works.

```
ssh -L x:localhost:y snoopy
```

> means "Start an SSH connection to snoopy, and also listen on port x on my machine, and forward any connections there to port y on snoopy."

To connect the remote display :1 to your local display :1, use:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 moms-computer
```

Longer explanation: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html

**[EDIT]** As to why capturing the output of some commands doesn't work: Some commands (like `less`) expect a TTY (a true terminal with the capability to move the cursor around, display colors, etc) as stdout. Those don't work or don't work correctly when you redirect stdout to a pipe or file.

Now why doesn't `cat` work? Your command redirects only stdout. If `cat` can't find the file, the error will be printed to stderr, not stdout and you won't see anything.

That's the only reason I can think of when `ls` works; both `ls` and `cat` are simple commands which don't care about TTY. They both inherit their stdout from the parent process and they both don't do anything special to stdout (well, `ls --color` gets the escape sequences from termcap).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Aaron. Indeed I know VNC+SSH is the way to go. But now I really wanted to know why exactly the NC way is failing.

Comment: See my edits. Most likely `cat` and `more` can't find the file which you specified. With your setup, you can't see errors. It can't be much else when `ls` alone works.

Comment: Many thanks Aaron for the detailed explanation. I find it very strange why ls works but not cat. I am certain the file that I'm looking for is there. (I created a file to test)

Comment: Maybe `nc` flags stdout as "not inheritable" but I don't know if that's possible or whether it does that. Just use SSH :-)